# Вставка в БД с возвратом первичного ключа

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Даны две таблицы T1 и T2.
 В T1 есть поле id с авто инкрементом;T2 есть поле parent которое содержит id родителя из таблицы T2.
Я хочу записать данные в таблицу T1 и сразу же получить значение поле id(оно же заранее не известно) а затем это значение записать в поле parent таблицы T2.
Должно выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
INSERT INTO T2(parent)
VALUES ( INSERT INTO T1(сol1, col2) VALUES('petya','petrov') return id )
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: [SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

адаптация [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18069213/4827341).

получить последнее авто-сгенерированное значение (для стобца, описанного как `auto_increment`) можно с помощью функции [last_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html).

«правильнее» всего (для избежания возможных «накладок» при одновременной вставке строк разными процессами) использовать транзакции.

но если вы вполне уверены, что конкуренция невозможна, можете смело опустить «обрамляющие» транзакцию выражения `start transaction` и `commit`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da1a/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t1 (id int auto_increment primary key, n text);
create table t2 (pid int not null, foreign key (pid) references t1(id), n text);

start transaction;
insert into t1 values (null, "иванов");
insert into t2 values (last_insert_id(), "иван");
commit;

start transaction;
insert into t1 values (null, "петров");
insert into t2 values (last_insert_id(), "пётр");
commit;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.id, t1.n, t2.n
from t1
left join t2 on t2.pid = t1.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da1a/1/0)**:

```
| id |      n |    n |
|----|--------|------|
|  1 | иванов | иван |
|  2 | петров | пётр |
```

**Query 2**:

```
show index from t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da1a/1/1)**:

```
| TABLE_NAME | NON_UNIQUE | INDEX_NAME | SEQ_IN_INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | COLLATION | CARDINALITY | SUB_PART | PACKED | NULLABLE | INDEX_TYPE | COMMENT | INDEX_COMMENT |
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|----------|------------|---------|---------------|
|         t1 |          0 |    PRIMARY |            1 |          id |         A |           2 |   (null) | (null) |          |      BTREE |         |               |
```

**Query 3**:

```
show index from t2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da1a/1/2)**:

```
| TABLE_NAME | NON_UNIQUE | INDEX_NAME | SEQ_IN_INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | COLLATION | CARDINALITY | SUB_PART | PACKED | NULLABLE | INDEX_TYPE | COMMENT | INDEX_COMMENT |
|------------|------------|------------|--------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|----------|------------|---------|---------------|
|         t2 |          1 |        pid |            1 |         pid |         A |           2 |   (null) | (null) |          |      BTREE |         |               |
```

Comment: А какого рода накладки с конкурентной вставкой вы предполагаете? `last_insert_id()` работает на уровне соединения с БД, так что для конкурентных запросов будет возвращать правильные значения в зависимости от соединения. Сами операции вставки атомарны. Я что-то упускаю?

Comment: @n0rd, насколько я понимаю, технически **возможно** использовать одно и то же соединение (см., например, php-шный [mysql_pconnect](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-pconnect.php)). потому «соломку подостлать» вряд ли будет лишним.

Comment: @n0rd, например, вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5687681/4827341) пишут, что риск таки есть.

Comment: `mysql_pconnect` предполагает переиспользование одного соединения (если я правильно понимаю документацию), т.е. ни о какой конкуренции речь не идет (нельзя одновременно выполнять два запроса через одно соединение). А проблема с неудачной вставкой в `t1`  при использовании `mysql_pconnect` будет присутствовать и при использовании транзакций, как мне кажется (в этом конкретном случае - вряд ли, но в общем, транзакции от нее не защищают).

Comment: Да нет там никаких накладок без использования pconnect. @n0rd - имеется в виду случай, когда между инсертом и получением id параллельный процесс использует то же подключение для своего инсерта - тут уж вопрос, как это постоянное подключение переиспользуется (хотя, скорее всего, эксклюзивно выделяется одному процессу).

Comment: Резюмирую: last_insert_id может быть "чужим" **только в пределах общего соединения mysql**. Транзакции тут не при чём, т.к. автоинкремент работает вне транзакций.